# RangeBar with ApexChart error: axis.min cannot be greater than axis.max apexchart:6 value()

Tags: codepen, apexcharts

I’m trying to plot this chart, and here, in codepen

[CodePen Code](https://codepen.io/holajuanfe/pen/PoPBooG?editors=0010)

It works,

But in my web site, i get in console, this error.

axis.min cannot be greater than axis.max apexchart:6 value()

```
var options = {
          series: [
          {
            name: 'Dan',
            data: [
              {
                x: 'Hands',
                y: [ new Date('2020-05-12T10:29:35.558Z').getTime(), new Date('2020-05-12T11:05:30.542Z').getTime()]
              },
              {
                x: 'Hands',
                y: [ new Date('2020-05-12T11:09:35.558Z').getTime(), new Date('2020-05-12T11:31:30.542Z').getTime()]
              },
            ]
          }
        ],
          chart: {
          height: 450,
          type: 'rangeBar'
        },
        plotOptions: {
          bar: {
            horizontal: true,
            barHeight: '80%'
          }
        },
        xaxis: {
          type: 'datetime'
        },
        stroke: {
          width: 1
        },
        fill: {
          type: 'solid',
          opacity: 0.6
        },
        legend: {
          position: 'top',
          horizontalAlign: 'left'
        }
        };

        var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
        chart.render();
```

[web site image view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuBM9.jpg)

Can you help me please to find why?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

In the setup of the chart, take a look in the space

```
Window.apex Objetc
```

And try to find inside a pre—setup.